# How to create a controller outside application folder in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have created a controller in a file which is outside application folder. But it throws error Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found. Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Comment: And why would you need a controller outside the application folder?

Comment: Better use [HMVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: because it is a file separate from the application but still part of the project, accessible outside the application folder.

Comment: I agree with @KishorSubedi. https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc‎
 is a good starting HMVC library for Codeigniter.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. It either is part of your application or it isn't. Can't have it both ways (not to say it would be impossible to connect, just that why would you?)

If it is a file that looks and works exactly like a controller then why on earth would you take it outside? If you re-route your index.php, then calling your controller's function yoursite.com/controller/function is the same as calling a file that was outside application folder. Suppose you had a folder on root called "controller" and a folder inside it called "function" and an index.php inside of it. You'd call both of them exactly same!

Bottom line: its ok to have 3rd party files outside of application folder, but to have a controller as-is outside of its place simply makes no sense, whatsoever.

Comment: I need to do this just because I need to commit my views/controllers/models to source control, but I don't want to commit framework files. An easier way would be to add names of these framework folders into `.gitignore` file, but the default `.gitignore`  doesn't do that, so I'm confused which way to go.